# Personalization in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, segments

I've followed below mentioned `Youtube` link for creation of `Personalization` . Once I've created the demo page in geometrixx site and put the content, I don't see the option to target the content on the right click of the content. Please let me know how can I do that?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWXMAQcRmEU

**Just FYI - I am AEM 6.1**

Also, I have followed the below mentioned Adobe documentation. In the teaser creation section, they create a new page using the "Teaser page template" but I don't see that template in the local. I can see the "**Experience template**". Let me know how can I've this template.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/personalization/campaigns/teasers-and-strategies.html

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are using AEM6.1, I am making the assumption that you are using Sightly markup (not jsp) and also TouchUI interface rather than ClassicUI. If not...you should be!! :)

In your head include data-sly-include="/libs/cq/cloudserviceconfigs/components/servicelibs/servicelibs.jsp" to pick up your target cloud service configuration.

inside the top of your body include data-sly-resource="${ @path='clientcontext', resourceType='cq/personalization/components/clientcontext'}"   to add Targeting mode to the client context menu

and before your closing body tag include data-sly-resource="${ @path='cloudservices', resourceType='cq/cloudserviceconfigs/components/servicecomponents'}"  to close your cloud services config

```html
<html lang="en" data-sly-use.clientLib="${'/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html'}">>
<head data-sly-use.head="head.js"
          data-sly-use.headlibRenderer="headlibs.html"
          data-sly-use.clientLib="${'/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html'}">
  
  <!-- your other client libs/css  etc --> 

  <sly data-sly-include="/libs/cq/cloudserviceconfigs/components/servicelibs/servicelibs.jsp" />
</head>
  
<body>
  <sly data-sly-resource="${ @path='clientcontext', resourceType='cq/personalization/components/clientcontext'}"  />
  
  <!-- BODY CONTENTS -->

  <sly data-sly-resource="${ @path='cloudservices', resourceType='cq/cloudserviceconfigs/components/servicecomponents'}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Just an FYI....teasers are old terminology (pre 6.1) ...use the experience template.

Comment: Was this of any help?

Comment: Great! now if only @user3451326 would accept this answer as correct :)